# How to log out of InAppBrowser Facebook login

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am using Cordova, but it doesn't necessarily matter for this case I think. Basically Facebook's login gives you the option of signing in directly on the InAppBrowser or to use the native app if installed. If someone signs in with the InAppBrowser, then there is no way of clearing it, even if you log them out. There must be a way to do it.